# Catch EADDRINUSE from ChildProcess

Tags: node.js, error-handling, child-process, httpserver

I have a spawn process running the http-server. This is my simplified code:

```js
const params = ['node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server', '--cors', '-p'];
const proc = cp.spawn('node', params, { stdio: 'inherit' });
// the next callback is never triggered
proc.on('error', err => {
  log(err.toString(), LogType.Error); // this is my custom log method
  process.exit(1);
});
```

When the previous process haven't been cleaned up properly the port would be still in use causing the **EADDRINUSE** error. I am trying to catch that error to properly report it to the user and exit the process, but I fail to catch the error.

I tried using on, emit, once, addListener, stderr, but nothing catches the error.

The process remains stuck and nothing is logged apart from internal error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:8082
  at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1259:14)
  at listenInCluster (net.js:1307:12)
  at doListen (net.js:1446:7)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
  at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:56:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:11)
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11

Emitted 'error' event at:
  at emitErrorNT (net.js:1286:8)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
  [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Comment: did you try listening to `.on('exit')` event?

Comment: both 'close' and 'exit' happen, but i'm not sure if this is enough. Ideally instead of showing the internal error I would like to catch it and show my error.